# Antónimo de "superar"

Tags: antónimos

Hoy ha surgido la duda sobre si existe algún antónimo de la palabra *superar*, especialmente refiriéndose a valores numéricos.

Por ejemplo, cuando un valor *supera* a otro, podemos decir que `5` supera a `3` o que es superior. ¿Hay algún equivalente inverso? ¿Algo que pueda expresarse con una sola palabra? 3 `{es inferior}` a 5. Donde `{es inferior}` es la palabra que busco

Comment: ¿Y si dices _no supera_? Si bien esto también incluiría la igualdad estricta.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @fedorqui. Una buena alternativa la propone Carlos Alejo, pero me parece que el mejor antónimo de "supera" es "no supera". _"Es inferior"_ tampoco esta nada mal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez podríamos usar *subyacer* (de conjugación rarísima):

> 1. intr. Yacer o estar debajo de algo.

No es transitivo y obliga una *a* como preposición de régimen *a*: **3 subyace a 5**.

También existe el verbo *desmerecer* que se define como lo siguiente:

> 3. intr. Dicho de una cosa: Ser inferior a otra con la cual se compara.

También intransitivo, para su complemento, emplea la preposición de régime *de*: **3 desmerece de 5**.

Comment: (que conste, personalmente, no usaría estas palabras porque me suenan algo raras en este contexto, pero bueno, antónimos técnicamente los son)

Comment: Curioso, a mí subyacer siempre me ha sonado a palabra para hablar de cosas metafísicas: siempre lo relaciono con problemas y traumas.

Comment: @fedorqui Bueno, es como lo suelo usar yo (el sentido figurativo/metafísico), aunque un par de veces lo he usado en su sentido literal, casi siempre al hablar de algo de arquitectura o cosas así.

Comment: Al que me votó en negativo, ¿puedes explicar por qué?

Answer (score 2):

No sé si es lo que buscas, pero a mí se me ocurre

> 3 **precede** a 5.

Aunque el verbo *[preceder](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Tuvu3IR)* no es exactamente un antónimo de *superar*, cumple con los requisitos de decir lo contrario y es una única palabra.